# prevent autodropdown by jquery datepicker

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

when I append jquery datepicker to my asp textbox, by clicking on it, my browser auto shows the history of the dates i typed in a dropdownlist. Can I prevent this?

Set textbox to readonly isn't a good idea because asp.net doesn't read the values from read only fields in code behind.

any other ideas?

thank you and best regards.

marc

Answer (score 0):

if the field is inside a form add

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to the form. 
For example:

```
<form action=".." method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

This should prevent the autocomplete function to be activated on the fields inside the form.
I don't know if it works on every browser.

Comment: thank you but it's asp.net and the whole site is into the form tag. I just want to do that on the specific page.